# AC Compressor Bracket Broken After Poorly Attached Undercarriage Skid Plate?

Tags: compressor

**TL;DR** My AC compressor bracket broke yesterday and a mechanic forgot to fully attach my undercarriage skid plate last week. Are the two related or is this just bad luck? Vehicle is a 2012 Honda Civic LX

**Full details:**

I took my car in for an oil change last week and ended up needing new oil pan, tires and front brake rotors. At the end, the mechanic forgot to fully attach the undercarriage skid plate.

I went on a road trip this weekend (~1000 miles) and discovered the undercarriage skid plate was hitting  the ground while I was on the highway. I got a temporary fix at a Honda dealership (zip tying the piece up) and I planned to go back to the mechanic to get it fully fixed.

Yesterday (after the road trip), my car started making a squealing sound which the same mechanic diagnosed as a broken AC compressor bracket and said he hadn't seen anything like it before.

Could something with the undercarriage skid plate affect my AC compressor bracket, or are the two events unrelated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The skid plate will usually be attached to the subframe or chassis while the compressor bracket will be attached to the engine.

The engine may well be mounted to the subframe and / or chassis but will have rubber mounts to reduce the vibration.

So, these events are most likely due to coincidence.

However, some cars are known to break brackets - one model I remember was really good at breaking alternator brackets due to fatigue, and that was due to the flexing imparted from the belt "pulling" the alternator as the engine changed speed.